# Excel Function SumIfs

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was wondering if it is possible to sum data(I know now you have to use Sum if) if it meets a certain criteria but I was wondering if you had two columns, A and B, where if say B1 is zero when you sumif from a different sheet leave it as 0, but if not, then Add up with the same formula the sumif value you would’ve got + A1 value.

Is it possible to do it in one formula and how, so basically while doing the sumif, if it’s zero leave it as zero, if not, then add up the value of the previous coloumn to the one calculated all in one cell

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: So suppose you have in A1 already a value of 4, and if you calculate SumIf(the SumIf has to calculated in Cell B1) and you get 5, then the value in Cell B1 should be 9, but if the SumIf was 0, then value in B1 would be 0...this code should be able to be dragged to other rows and columns.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1507469/edit) instead of adding information in comments. it might be useful to upload some screencaps to http://imgur.com and link to them here

Comment: @BasicBase,, what you are trying is possible but no use of SUMIF,, it's adding existing value with adjacent cell if meets the criteria,,, this can be executed either using the Excel function or VBA macro. BUT better  [Edit]  you post & share sample data since you need to access another Sheet in case cell value is ZERO !!

Answer (score 0):

citing :

> if say B1 is zero when you sumif from a different sheet leave it as 0, but if not, then Add up with the same formula the sumif value you would’ve got + A1 value

in C1 put :

```
=if(B1=0,0,A1+B1)
```

please share if it works/not.